# What was the view of rhyme scheme during the tin pan alley era with 32 bar songs?

Tags: rhyme-schemes

I've noticed some of the 32 bar songs from the tin pan alley era have rhyme scheme all over the place. Did they care about rhyme scheme? From what sources did they learn to use rhyme scheme?

Gene Autry who used many songwriters work from tin pan alley had many songs with unorganized rhyme scheme. aabbccddee  and aabbaaccdd and abba and abcbddef and many more seemingly random rhyme schemes.

Comment: It would be helpful to give some examples of what you've noticed. Right now the question suffers a bit from a blanket generalization (I'm sure not all Tin Pan Alley writers learned from the same sources). I'll also suggest that such songs often feature internal rhymes and generous half-rhymes.

Comment: Also, a clarification on the aabbccddee-style notation, which is new to me. Does each line represent one line of vocals? Can we get a quick example of a well-known song with its rhyme scheme dissected in that notation? You know, just to help us answer more easily.

Comment: @AndyBonner and more.  Unconventional rhyming was common, such as Lorenz Hart's rhyming "by" and "July" with the first syllable of "gliding," leaving "ding" as the first syllable of the following line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not particularly unusual rhyme schemes in English (and Italian) poetry. The aabbccddee... is just a string of couplets (Alexander Pope); abba is called an "enclosed" rhyme and is very common. Sometimes one gets abccba similarly. ("Big Spender" does something similar.) Varying rhyme schemes has always been popular with poets and lyricists.

Roses are red, violets are blue, sugar is sweet some of the time.
Something is wrong twixt me and you, we got the juice but never the wine. (doesn't really rhyme though)

Roses are red, violets are blue,
You'll be surprised when this doesn't rhyme.

Roses are red, violets are purple.
Sugar is sweet, so's maple surple.

All these have been used over the years. If it fits, it's good.

Comment: There are a lot of types of rhyme; words like "time" and "wine" are sometimes called _slant rhymes_. Traditional poetry has made much use of these more general types of rhyme, so I don't know why Tin Pan Alley would be any different. I wonder if some of OP's discovered rhyme schemes are ignoring these types of rhyming.